# "Error establishing a database connection" on blogoverflow.com

Tags: bug, blog-overflow

I get the following error message when I try to go to http://blogoverflow.com/

Not sure if its down for maintenance or something. Just a heads up.

**Firefox:**

> [image: blogoverflow error on Firefox]

**Chrome:**

> [image: blogoverflow error on Chrome]

**IE10**

> [image: blogoverflow error on IE10]

Comment: Subdomains like http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/ are still working.

Comment: @Jehof so it's been down for 3 months?

Comment: @Stijn at least it seems to be related.

Comment: @stijn also has the response a HTTP-Status Code 200 so it seems that the message is meant to be

Comment: @Jehof since that post is 3 months old, shouldn't that possibly be a separate issue even though it results in the same error?

Comment: Did it work at some point within the last 3 months?